# Verizon says Ellipsis 8 does not support USB Debugging

Tags: android, usb, ellipsis

Has anyone one gotten Win 7, Verizon Ellipsis 8 to work with USB debugging. 
 - Talked with 2 different people at level 2 support at Verizon. 
   Both no help though they tried. 1st pointed to Google/Android and gave me
   a support number there.
 - Google says Verizon's fault due to modified/customized OS. They even
   tried to point to hardware manufacturer 
 - Verizon "Store" guy did some research and finally said, sorry this tablet
   won't support USB debugging. However, this LG will (so the web page(s)
   he was looking at said).

I can get table to connect at CD Rom but there are no drivers to be found on tablet. The store guy suggested I "Root" the tablet but said if I break it, no support. Great. And he didn't have any faith in that either.

Device driver will ONLY show USB as a QTAQZ3... and there is even a minor conflict between portable device and USB device.

Has anyone managed to get the Verizon Ellipsis 8 to work? Somewhere I read that someone had/has the Ellipsis 7 working....

Thank you,

Ernie

Comment: Any luck getting this working? I am having the same problem. I have not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Get to settings, at the bottom of the list touch "*About tablet*". Tap on SW version or HW version several times (I honestly tapped both alternately) until you see "*you are 1 tap away from being a developer!*". One more tap, then go back and find "*Developer Options*", which you can access to enable USB debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Tab the Build number several times in the About Tablet in the Setting. It took me 10 taps before debugging enabled.